# Toggle the colour of a button

Tags: c#, multithreading, button, togglebutton

I have created a program which contains threads. There is a button with a panel, when the panel is accessed by a thread , the button should turn its background colour to pink automatically. When the button is pressed again , it should turn green. My problem is when a thread access that panel , the button doesn't turn pink, it stays in its default colour. But when i click it changes colour.

Here is what i have done :-

//this is the button click event

```
public void btn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        locked = !locked; //makes the locked variable true if it is false and vice versa

        this.btn.BackColor = locked ? Color.Pink : Color.Green;

        lock (this)
        {
            if (!locked)
            {
                Monitor.Pulse(this);

            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code which is when executed, the button should automatically turn pink.

```
 public void start2()
        {
           Thread.Sleep(delay);


            while (true)
            {


            semaphore.Signal();
            this.ZeroPlane();
            panel.Invalidate();
            buff.read(ref colour, ref status);             

            for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
            {
                panel.Invalidate();
                this.movePlane(xDelta, yDelta);
                Thread.Sleep(delay);
                locked = true;
            }

            if (status == "1" || status =="2" || status == "3") //checks whether it has arrived at the destination
            {

                lock (this)
                {
                    while (locked)
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(this); //keep the plane in the hub  until the button is pressed.
                    }
                }
                semaphore.Wait();

                buff.write(this.colour, this.status); //overwrites the buffer 

                buff.read(ref colour, ref status);



                for (int p = 0; p < 5; p++)
                {
                    this.westEast = true;
                    this.movePlane(0, 20);
                    Thread.Sleep(delay);
                    panel.Invalidate();


                }
                nextSemaphore.Wait();
                nextBuffer.write(this.colour, "0");
                this.colour = Color.Yellow;
                this.status = null;

            }


        }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see where the Button's color is affected by the thread.

Comment: @Shehan.W Do you really need the threading?

Comment: Yes i need threading.

Answer (score 1):

You have the button looking at the `locked` variable when the button is pressed, if it is locked (would be pink), then you immediately set it to not locked (green) when means that when you change the colour, it can only go to green, you didn't give it a chance to go to pink. The `Start2` method sets the `locked` variable, but then you have no way of additionally testing this to change the button (I assume you have discovered that changing the form from another thread is a no-go).

You have two options, make a timer that fires every 100 miliseconds-ish or something, that tests the 'locked' variable and sets the button to pink. This timer will be on the forms thread and so is allowed to change the button properties.

Elseways, you can make an event that acts as is a listener to the variable, and call the event to fire from inside your thread.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution. I just changed the backcolour of the button by using it's variable name.

Here is what i did:

```
         //more code here

         if (status == "1" || status =="2" || status == "3") //checks whether it has arrived at the destination

                   {

                    this.btn.BackColor = Color.Pink; //just change its colour to pink.
                    lock (this)
                    {
                    //rest of the code
```